# Individually change element inside of a class through their ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making a drawing board and as such need a color selector.

With the HTML I do plan to make them all different IDs. Right now all they do is change every single color, I just need it to change 1.

```js
$("#colour").change(function(event) {
  console.log($(this).val());
  $(".color_front").css('background-color', $(this).val());
});

$(".color_front").click(function(event) {
  $("#colour").click();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.color_div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type=color] {
  display: none;
}

span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

.color_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  max-width: 290px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="color_box">
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
  <div class="color_div">
    <span class="color_front"></span>
    <input type='color' value='#000000' class='bar' id="colour">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: IDs must be unique anyway or you have invalid HTML. Use classes and `$(this)` to select the parent element. There are probably a thousand similar questions on SO.

Comment: @isherwood Ok, so what do I do? Redirecting me to a question that has no compatibility with mine doesn't actually help me, against popular belief.

Comment: Apologies, I got your two similarly-named classes confused. The duplicate link has been updated. You don't need `parent()`. You need `prev()`. You can see for yourself the relationship between the changed element and the one you're targeting. Just think it through and it's fairly apparent.